# Manipulating dictionaries within lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with dictionaries in it as below:

```
wordsList = [
    {'Definition': 'Allows you to store data with ease' , 'Word': 'Database'},
    {'Definition': 'This can either be static or dynamic' , 'Word': 'IP'},
]
```

Essentially, what I want to do is:

- Be able to print each separate definition
- Be able to print each separate word

And so my question is: How do I do this? I only know how to do this with regular lists/dictionaries, not what I have here.

Comment: These look like regular lists and dictionaries. Why do you think they are not?

Answer (score 1):

```
for word_def in wordsList:
  print word_def.get("Word")
  print word_def.get("Definition")
  print
```

output

```
Database
Allows you to store data with ease

IP
This can either be static or dynamic
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, these are "regular" lists/dictionaries.

You must understand, that a list in Python can contain any object, also dicts. Thus, neither the list nor the contained dicts become anyhow "irregular".

You can access anything inside your list/dict like that:

```
word_def[index][name]
```

With appropriate values for index/name.

You can also iterate over the list (as shown by SSNR) and thus grab any of the dictionaries contained and deal with them like ordinary dicts.

You also can get hold of one of the dicts this way:

```
one_dict = word_def[index]
```

Than just access the contents:

```
value = one_dict[name]
```

Comment: Thanks, abit off-topic, how would I calculate the amount of dictionaries within the list

Comment: Just use len(word_def) as usual. The list works the same, regardless of the types of the contained elements.